# can't convert hashset to treeset with object collection

Tags: java, collections, set, hashset, treeset

I have to convert Hashset to TreeSet, but i have errors

```
// Here, All is ok, Chien is an object.
Set<Chien> animaux = new HashSet<Chien>();
animaux.add(new Chien("non", 10));
animaux.add(new Chien("zoz", 15));
animaux.add(new Chien("non", 10));

// And then i have to convert it to TreeSet 
// IntellJ-Idead says me that's ok...
// But i have an error here
TreeSet<Chien> treseet = new TreeSet<Chien>(animaux);
```

But when I try to compile :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: fr.univtln.arouani277.vertebre.animal.Chien cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:559)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:322)
    at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)
    at java.util.TreeSet.<init>(TreeSet.java:160)
    at fr.univtln.arouani277.App.main(App.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Here are my files `Chien` :

```
public class Chien extends Mammifere implements Ibruit {
    public Chien(String pnom, int page) {
        super(pnom, page);
    }

    public void aboyer() {
        System.out.println("ouaf");
    }

    public void crier() {
        System.out.println("ouaf");
    }
}
```

it extends `Mammifere` :

```
public abstract class Mammifere extends Animal {
    public Mammifere(String pnom, int page) {
        super(pnom, page);
    }
}
```

That extends `Animal` :

```
public abstract class Animal extends Vertebre {
    public Animal(String nom, int page) {
        super(nom, page);
    }

    public void aboyer() {
    }

    public String toString() {
        System.out.println("Je suis un animal");
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

that extends `Vertebre` :
http://pastebin.com/Aa4Rw8sW

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike a `HashSet`, a `TreeSet` relies on an ordering so it can quickly determine if there are duplicates.  When you pass in the `HashSet` to the [`TreeSet` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet--), it finds that your `Chien` objects aren't `Comparable`.

> Constructs a new tree set containing the elements in the specified collection, sorted according to the natural ordering of its elements. All elements inserted into the set must implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all such elements must be mutually comparable: e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the set.

You have 2 options:

- Have your `Chien` class implement `Comparable<Chien>` to fulfill this requirement.
- Create your [`TreeSet` with your custom implementation of `Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-).  Then call `addAll`, passing your `HashSet`.  The `Comparator` establishes the order instead of the class being `Comparable`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you what is wrong:

> ClassCastException: fr.univtln.arouani277.vertebre.animal.Chien cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

You should make your class `Chien` implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). This is documented in the constructor of [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Collection-) (emphasis mine):

> Constructs a new tree set containing the elements in the specified collection, sorted according to the natural ordering of its elements. **All elements inserted into the set must implement the Comparable interface.** Furthermore, all such elements must be mutually comparable: e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the set.

This is expected because a `TreeSet` orders its element so it has to know how to compare them.

Since you are building a complex class hierarchy, maybe the `Comparable` interface should be implemented by the top class `Vertebre`. This is depending of how you want to actually do the comparison.